# Why is this for loop running so many times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Below is the code for a component I'm working on with React. It takes a list of stocks and using FinancialModelingPrep's API it gets me the historical month end price. I'm using the console.log in the getPrice function to see what's wrong as its causing me to hit my API limit in 1 invocation, when it should only make 15 calls per invocation. I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my logic as the console.log shows each stock in the array 100 times or so. Any help with this could be great.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import apiKey from '../../config.js'


class Holdings extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: props.list
    }
    this.getNames = this.getNames.bind(this)
    this.getPrice = this.getPrice.bind(this)
  }

  getNames(obj) {
    let last = obj[Object.keys(obj)[Object.keys(obj).length - 1]]
    for (let i = 0; i < last.length; i++) {
      this.getPrice(last[i])
      console.log(last[i])
    }
    return last
  }

  getPrice(name) {
    let year = new Date().getFullYear()
    let month = new Date().getMonth()
    let prevMonthEnd = {
      0: year - 1 + '-12-31',
      1: year + '-01-31',
      2: year + '-02-28',
      3: year + '-03-31',
      4: year + '-04-30',
      5: year + '-05-31',
      6: year + '-06-30',
      7: year + '-07-31',
      8: year + '-08-31',
      9: year + '-09-30',
      10: year + '-10-31',
      11: year + '-11-30',
    }
    let ticker = name['Ticker'].split(' ')[0]
    axios.get(`https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-price-full/${ticker}?from=${prevMonthEnd[month]}&to=${prevMonthEnd[month]}&apikey=${apiKey['TOKEN']}`)
      .then(res => {
        name['Beg Month Price'] = res.data['historical'][0]['close']
      })
      .then(() => console.log('New Stock: ', name))
      .catch(error => console.log('error with API: ', error))
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Current Portfolio Holdings</h3>
        <table className="table table-striped table-sm">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Ticker</td>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>MTD Return</td>
            </tr>
            {this.getNames(this.state.data).map((i, key) => {
              return <tr key={key++}>
                <td>{i['Ticker'].split(' ')[0]}</td>
                <td>{i['Name']}</td>
                <td>{i['Beg Month Price']}</td>
              </tr>
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I feel the error lies at `let last = obj[Object.keys(obj)[Object.keys(obj).length - 1]]`.
Would you be able to share a sample obj (stock list)?

Comment: Also, why do you have the same from and to in API request at `?from=${prevMonthEnd[month]}&to=${prevMonthEnd[month]}` ?

Comment: Sure. Here is an example of what it would look like. It's an array of 15 of these:

{1M Return: "0"
2M Return: "0"
3M Return: "0"
Current Ratio: "1.719715808"
Debt/ Equity Ratio: "158.6905949"
Div Yield: "0.8153"
Earnings Yield: "3.3822"
FCF Growth: "9.211694885"
GICS Sector: "Financials"
Market Cap: "Large"
Name: "S&P Global Inc"
Operating Margin: "51.69630643"
Operating Margin Growth: "10.55258074"
ROA: "24.98151571"
Rank: 41.833333333333336
Rankings: (6) [50, 1, 89, 32, 0, 79]
Ticker: "SPGI US EQUITY"}

Comment: To your 2nd question, its just the way the endpoints are. I only need it for 1 specific day in the past so I have to make the "from" and "to" parts the same day as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Is this possibly an issue where a rerender is occurring in the containing application? You could check `componentDidUpdate` to verify if that might be the cause.